# how to download a file returned "indirectly"(??) from html form submission? (python, urllib, urllib2, etc.)

Tags: python, forms, download, urllib2, urllib

EDIT:  Problem solve.  Ultimately it turned out to be a matter of "http:" instead of "https:" in the url (just a stupid mistake on my part).  But it was the nice clean code example from cetver that helped me isolate the problem.  Thanks to all who offered suggestions.

Putting this url in firefox triggers the appropriate download and save-as dialog:

```
https://www.virwox.com/orders.php?download_open=Download&format_open=.xls
```

The above link is same as submitting form with a "download" button of form on the page https://www.virwox.com/orders.php.

Here is the relevant html for the form that generates the above url:

```
<form action='orders.php' method='get'><fieldset><legend>Open Orders (2):</legend>
  <input type='submit' value='Download' name='download_open' /> 
  <select name='format_open'>
    <option value='.xls'>.xls</option>
    <option value='.csv'>.csv</option>
    <option value='.xml'>.xml</option></select>
</form>
```

But when I try the following python code (which I sort of expected would not work)...

```
# get orders list
openOrders_url = virwoxTopLevel_url+"/orders.php"
openOrders_params = urlencode( { "download_open":"Download", "format_open":".xml" } )
openOrders_request = urllib2.Request(openOrders_url,openOrders_params,headers)
openOrders_response = virwox_opener.open(openOrders_request)
openOrders_xml = openOrders_response.read()
print(openOrders_xml)
```

...openOrders_xml ends up just being the original page (https://www.virwox.com/orders.php).

How does firefox know there is also a file to be downloaded, and how do I detect and download this file in Python?

Please note that this is not a security/login issue, as I would not even be able to get the orders.php page if I was having authentication trouble.

EDIT:  I am wondering if this has something to do with redirection (I am using the basic redirection handler) or maybe I should be using something liek urllib.fileretrieve().

EDIT:  here is code for complete program, just in case is relevant...

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import pprint

from urllib import urlencode

username=###############
password=###############

virwoxTopLevel_url = "http://www.virwox.com/"

overview_url = "https://www.virwox.com/index.php"


# Header
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

# Handlers...
# cookie handler...
cookie_handler= urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor( cookielib.CookieJar() )
# redirect handler...
redirect_handler= urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler()

# create "opener" (OpenerDirector instance)
virwox_opener = urllib2.build_opener(redirect_handler,cookie_handler)

# login
login_url = "https://www.virwox.com/index.php"
values = { 'uname' : username, 'password' : password }
login_data = urllib.urlencode(values)
login_request = urllib2.Request(login_url,login_data,headers)
login_response = virwox_opener.open(login_request)

overview_html = login_response.read();

virwox_json_url = "http://api.virwox.com/api/json.php"
getTest = urllib.urlencode( { "method":"getMarketDepth", "symbols[0]":"EUR/SLL","symbols[1]":"USD/SLL","buyDepth":1,"sellDepth":1,"id":1 } )
get_response = urllib2.urlopen(virwox_json_url,getTest)
#print get_response.read()

# get orders list
openOrders_url = virwoxTopLevel_url+"/orders.php"
openOrders_params = urlencode( { "download_open":"Download", "format_open":".xml" } )
openOrders_request = urllib2.Request(openOrders_url,openOrders_params,headers)
openOrders_response = virwox_opener.open(openOrders_request)
openOrders_xml = openOrders_response.read()

# the following prints the html of the /orders.php page not the desired download data:
print "******************************************"
print(openOrders_xml)

print "******************************************"
print openOrders_response.info()
print openOrders_response.geturl()
print "******************************************"
# the following prints nothing, i assume because without the cookie handler, fails to authenticate
#  (note that authentication is by the php program, not html authentication, so no "authentication hangler" above
print urllib2.urlopen("https://www.virwox.com/orders.php?download_open=Download&format_open=.xml").read()
```

Comment: Did you check exactly what firefox is sending in its request? Is a browser user-agent required?, are their other hidden fiels/values?

Comment: I am pretty sure I am sending exactly what firefox is sending.  Here is what "Live HTTP Header" shows me when I click the "download" button:

Comment: oops, here is it:  `GET /orders.php?download_open=Download&format_open=.xls&format_historic=.xls

`

Comment: also, as I said I can put the url as shown exactly into the address bar of firefox.  (not also that that extra param "format_historic" is irrelevant and can be left off, or not, no difference).

Comment: does `urlopen(https://www.virwox.com/orders.php?download_open=Download&format_open=.xls).read()` get the data you need?

Comment: no, that returns nothing -- I assume because it does not use my virwox_opener which handles the cookies involved with the php login (or maybe it is the headers in the Request that are needed).  At any rate the naked url is not sufficient.

Comment: could there be some kind of "handler" that I need to handle whatever is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CODE BELLOW ISN'T TESTED**

something like:

```
import urllib, urllib2,

HOST = 'https://www.virwox.com'
FORMS = {
    'login': {
        'action': HOST + '/index.php',
        'data': urllib.urlencode( {
            'uname':'username', 
            'password':'******'
        } )
    },
    'orders': {
        'action': HOST + '/orders.php',
        'data': urllib.urlencode( {
            'download_open':'Download', 
            'format_open':'.xml'
        } )
    }
}

opener = urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor() )
try:
    req = urllib2.Request( url = FORMS['login']['action'], data = FORMS['login']['data'] )
    opener.open( req ) #save login cookie
    print 'Login: OK'
except Exception, e:
    print 'Login: Fail'
    print e   
try:
    req = urllib2.Request( url = FORMS['orders']['action'], data = FORMS['orders']['data'] )
    print 'Orders Page: OK'
except Exception, e:
    print 'Orders Page: Fail'
    print e
try:
    xml = opener.open( req ).read()
    print xml
except Exception, e:
    print 'Obtain XML: Fail'
    print e
```

Comment: Thanks cetver.  I'll try that.  But aside from your much cleaner coding style, I'm not sure, at first glance, that you do anything different semantically.  Looks like you build the same opener, requests, and use same methods.

Comment: Hey, it worked!   Hmmm... but why?  Looking closer I see you left out the redirect handler in the opener.  Is that it?  Was my redirect handler catching something that sent it back to the original page ignoring the data in between (so to speak)?

Comment: there is not semantically differences same language, same libs. Then i wrote this code, your listing does not exist or I did not notice it

Comment: `build_opener` have `default_classes = [ProxyHandler, UnknownHandler, HTTPHandler,HTTPDefaultErrorHandler, HTTPRedirectHandler,FTPHandler, FileHandler, HTTPErrorProcessor]` as you see `HTTPRedirectHandler` is one of their, so no need to call it manually.

Comment: Well, writing nice clean code is the real answer here.  After carefully comparing your code with mine, I finally noticed that I had slipped an http: instead of https: into the url, and that was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your question is already answered, but you might like to take a look at the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) package. It is basically a nice wrapper around the standard lib tools. The following (probably) does what you want.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.virwox.com/orders.php', 
    allow_redirects=True,
    auth=('user', 'pass'), 
    data={'download_open': 'Download', 'format_open': '.xls'})

print r.content
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need a `urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgr` like this (untested since I dont have your uname/pw):

```
import urllib
import urllib2

uri = "http://www.virwox.com/"
url = uri + "orders.php"
uname = "USERNAME"
password = "PASSWORD"
post = urllib.urlencode({"download_open":"Download", "format_open":".xls"})
pwMgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgr()
pwMgr.add_password(realm=None, uri=uri, user=uname, passwd=password)
urllib2.install_opener(urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(pwMgr)))
req = urllib2.Request(url, post)
s = urllib2.urlopen(req)
cookie = s.headers['Set-Cookie']
s.close()

req.add_header('Cookie', cookie)

s = urllib2.urlopen(req)
source = s.read()
s.close()
```

Then, you can:

```
print source
```

to see if it contains the xml data you need.